# Override warning

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть класс

```
class Base {
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

В нем перекрывается метод `toString` без нотации `@override`. При компиляции в IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 я ожидаю увидеть warning, но его нет. Добавлял в параметры компилятора Settings -> Compiler -> Java compiler -> Additional command line параметры `-Xlint`, `-Xlint:all`, `-Xlint:overrides` - никакого эффекта не возымело. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Есть не плохой ответ на данную тему
http://stackoverflow.com/a/94411/5650472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ был найден на англоязычном SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330275/javac-xlintoverrides-not-working Спасибо @post_zeew

Проблему отсутствия `@Override` компилятор не отслеживает (данная директива запрещает перекрывать **отсутствующий** метод). Но может отследить сама IDE. Для этого нужно зайти в Settings -> Editor -> Inspections и настроить параметр `Missing @Override annotations`. При этом можно еще снять чекбокс с опции `ignore 'equals()', 'hashCode()' and 'toString() methods'.

Answer (score 2):

Суть аннотации `@override` заключается в проверке наличия аннотируемого метода в суперклассе и не более того.

В случае переопределения метода без аннотации – никаких предупреждений быть не должно.

Вот если бы Вы указали аннотацию `@override` для метода, которого нет в суперклассе, то в этом случае IDE бы известила Вас об этом.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо. А нет ли способа выдавать warning в моем случае? При переопределении существующего метода без @Override?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Честно говоря не знаю. [Вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330275/javac-xlintoverrides-not-working), кстати, человек задается подобным вопросом. Может быть в ответах на него найдете что-нибудь полезное.